# using the laws of set algebra to simplify $(A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B^c)^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am told to use the laws of set algebra to simplify $(A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B^c)^c$.

And I need to show the reason for each step.

$(A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B^c)^c$

$= (A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cup B)$ By De Morgan's law.

$= (B^c \cap A) \cup (A \cup B)$ By commutativity.

$= B^c \cap (A \cup A) \cup B$ By associativity.

$= B^c \cap A \cup B$ By idempotence.

$= B^c \cap B \cup A$ by commutativity

$= \emptyset \cup A$ Since we have intersection with complement.

$= A$ By identity laws.

Does this all look correct? If not then what is the correct way? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens if A is false and B is true? I would re-examine the last four lines.

Comment: @JohnDouma What is wrong with it? I do not see anything?

Comment: What do you get when A is false and B is true? You don't get A.

Comment: @JohnDouma okay I see. But then where did I make the error? I cannot see any misuse of set theory laws.

Comment: The third line with the = sign is incorrect. You cannot use associativity there.

Comment: $(B^\complement\cap A)\cup A\cup B=((B^\complement \cap A)\cup A)\cup B$ by associativity.  Next use absorption...

Comment: @GrahamKemp After using absorption we get $((B^\complement \cap A)\cup A)\cup B = A \cup B$. Is this the simplification done? Solution finished?

Comment: Yes.  You cannot make it any simpler than that, @Wyuw.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Great. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 to 4 is the issue, ie $(B^c \cap A) \cup (A \cup B) \neq B^c \cap (A \cup A) \cup B$.

For any four sets $A, B, C$ and $D$ associativity implies that $(A \cap B) \cup (C \cup D) = ((A \cap B) \cup C) \cup ((A \cap B) \cup D)$ so in this case we have that
$$ (B^c \cap A) \cup (A \cup B) = ((B^c \cap A) \cup A) \cup ((B^c \cap A) \cup B)$$

But this step is not necessary since as stated by @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani, you just need to notice that $B^c \cap A \subseteq A$ and therefore $(B^c \cap A) \cup (A \cup B) = A \cup B$

Answer (score 0):

Note that at $$(B^c \cap A) \cup (A \cup B)$$ we have $$(B^c \cap A) \subseteq (A \cup B) $$

Therefore the answer should be $$(B^c \cap A) \cup (A \cup B)=  (A \cup B)$$